# $x \sin x=2$ why is my proof that there no solutions wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles, fake-proofs

$\frac 12 x \sin x=1$ . Let's look at a right triangle with base $x$ and altitude $\sin x$ . Then our equation is for the area of this triangle. Let the sides of the triangle be $a=x$ , $b=\sqrt {x^2+sin^2 x}$ , and $c= \sin x$ . According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), Heron's formula can be written as $$A=\large \frac { \sqrt {4a^2c^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}}{4}$$

Plugging in:

$4=\large \sqrt{4x^2 \sin^2 x-(x^2+x^2+\sin^2 x-\sin ^2 x)^2}$

$4=x^2 \sin^2 x -x^4$

$x^2(x^2- \sin^2 x)=-4$

$x^2$ will always be positive, and $\sin^2 x$ is never greater than $x^2$ , so this equation can have no real solutions. The original has solutions, so why is this wrong?

Comment: an application of the intermediate value theorem to say $x=0$ and $x=12\pi +\pi/2$ shows there must be a solution.

Comment: Yea I know wolframalpha says there are infinitely many

Comment: draw a graph of $y = x \sin x,$ say for $0 \leq x \leq 4 \pi.$

Comment: I think this particular wikipedia formula is *wrong*, probably it is $a^2-b^2+c^2$ correctly if starts with $4a^2c^2$. Try it out with arbitrary right triangle. There's negative under the square root in your case!!

Comment: What you're proving is that there are no triangles of the dimensions you specify. And that have an area of 1.

Comment: What @Berci said. The "equivalent Chinese formula" poses conditions, which are not satisfied by your choices. The one whose square is subtracted must be the medium side, and the pure square term involves the longest and shortest side.

Comment: I've updated the formula on Wikipedia, after verifying in Mathematica that Berci's comment is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This particular wikipedia formula is **wrong**.

It should be correctly either
$$A=\large \frac { \sqrt {4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}}{4}$$
or
$$A=\large \frac { \sqrt {4a^2c^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2)^2}}{4}\,.$$
Mind the symmetry..

Comment: The formula on Wikipedia is correct, but the OP copied it down incorrectly.

Comment: @wj32 I think I copied it down correctly but Rahul Narain said he just updated it on wikipedia.

Comment: Well, my browser (still) shows the cited version of the formula. However, Rahul Narain commented that he already corrected it in wiki..

Comment: +1 Thanks Berci, I will see what I get with this new formula later

Comment: Yeah, Wikipedia was updated today, no doubt as a result of this problem.

Comment: Ah, OK then.${}{}$

Comment: @Ovi: With $a=x$, $b=\sin x$, $c=\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}$, the formula just gives you back $\frac12x\sin x$. Not surprising, since we already know that's the area of the triangle...

Answer (score 4):

There are solutions on each interval $\left[2k\pi,2k\pi+\frac\pi2\right]$ for positive integer $k$ by the intermediate value theorem because $x\sin(x)$ is $0$ on the left end and $2k\pi+\frac\pi2$ on the right.

Heron's Formula should be
$$
A=\frac{\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}}{4}
$$
Does that cause the same problem?

Comment: Probably, but I will have time later to check